# How do I copy files with multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to copy files in 15-minute intervals. I do not want to use Task Scheduler.

Essentially, I execute all three threads and let the threads take care of themselves. Method `RunWhenItsTime()` basically monitors the current time and checks that RunTime is equal to CurrentTime. If it is, then `RunWhenItsTime()` calls `CopyFiles()` which begins copying files.

Should the following code work? For some reason, it gets stuck somewhere but I'm not sure where it is.

Here's my code:

```
Class myClass0 = new Class();
Thread0 = new Thread(() => myClass0.RunWhenItsTime(FirstQtrRun, 0, cts0.Token));
Thread0.Start();

Class myClass1 = new Class();
Thread1 = new Thread(() => myClass1.RunWhenItsTime(SecondQtrRun, 1, cts1.Token));
Thread1.Start();

Class myClass2 = new Class();
Thread2 = new Thread(() => myClass2.RunWhenItsTime(ThirdQtrRun, 2, cts2.Token));
Thread2.Start();

Class myClass3 = new Class();
Thread3 = new Thread(() => myClass3.RunWhenItsTime(FourthQtrRun, 3, cts2.Token));
Thread3.Start();

public void RunWhenItsTime(DateTime RunTime, int Period, Object obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task Has been set to run at: " + RunTime.ToString(), " for Period: " + Period.ToString());
    DateTime CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
    for (; ; )
    { //Check that CurrentTime is equal to RunTime.
        Console.WriteLine("Runtime: " + RunTime.ToString() + "   |   " + "Current Time: " + CurrentTime.ToString() 
            + "PERIOD: " + Period.ToString());
        if ((CurrentTime.Year == RunTime.Year) && (CurrentTime.Month == RunTime.Month) &&
            (CurrentTime.Day == RunTime.Day) && (CurrentTime.Hour == RunTime.Hour) &&
            (CurrentTime.Minute == RunTime.Minute))
        {
            CopyFiles(RunTime, Period, obj);
            break;
        }
        CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seriously using infinite loop instead of a timer or - even better - something like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net)?

Comment: Maybe they're using CPU utilization to check whether the scheduler still runs or not ;-)

Comment: I would prefer using Timers but haven't found a decent example. Let's say I want to invoke `CopyFiles()` at :00, :15, :30, :45. How would I do this with a Threading.Timer?

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek, I would prefer using Timers but haven't found a decent example. Let's say I want to invoke CopyFiles() at :00, :15, :30, :45. How would I do this with a Threading.Timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off your executing an infinite loop without letting the thread sleep when there is nothing to do (and your doing that 3 times), this will kill your CPU utilization:

```
for (; ; )
{ //Check that CurrentTime is equal to RunTime.
    Console.WriteLine("Runtime: " + RunTime.ToString() + "   |   " + "Current Time: " + CurrentTime.ToString() 
        + "PERIOD: " + Period.ToString());
    if ((CurrentTime.Year == RunTime.Year) && (CurrentTime.Month == RunTime.Month) &&
        (CurrentTime.Day == RunTime.Day) && (CurrentTime.Hour == RunTime.Hour) &&
        (CurrentTime.Minute == RunTime.Minute))
    {
        CopyFiles(RunTime, Period, obj);
        break;
    }
    CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
    System.Threading.Thread.Current.Sleep(1000);  // sleep 1 second
}
```

Secondly, you really should only have 1 loop, this single loop should determine if it's time to `CopyFiles` for any one of your 3 conditions and execute (Thread/Task it out if you want) that.  Once all 3 conditions are met, exit your timing loop.

Comment: Thanks. I had previously tried using a single loop to execute the threads, but there seemed to be an issue with the program being invoked. But now it works well. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't be using an infinite loop to do your direct testing of current time with time to kick of file copying. A better solution would be to use a C#'s `Timer` class. The following link has a very good example.

[Using C# Timer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

Using this method you could still use your threads but not eat up all of your CPU and would likely be MUCH more reliable.